# Array manipulation - lodash or underscore js

Tags: node.js, underscore.js, lodash

I have a requirement to change the format of an array in lodash or underscore:

```
[
    {
        name: "john",
        type: "facebook"
    },
    {
        name: "Mike",
        type: "facebook"
    },
    {
        name: "Jacob",
        type: "twitter"
    },
    {
        name: "Nancy",
        type: "twitter"
    },
    {
        name: "Antony",
        type: "facebook"
    },
    {
        name: "Viki",
        type: "linkedin"
    }
]
```

Need to convert above array to an object, as follows

```
{
    facebook: [
        {
            name: "john",
            type: "facebook"
        },
        {
            name: "Mike",
            type: "facebook"
        },
         {
            name: "Antony",
            type: "facebook"
        }
    ],
    twitter: [
         {
            name: "Jacob",
            type: "twitter"
        },
        {
            name: "Nancy",
            type: "twitter"
        }
    ],
    linkedin: [
        {
            name: "Viki",
            type: "linkedin"
        }
    ] 
}
```

I have tried the [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy) function, but that didn't work for me. So I don't have much sample code to show. It would be great help if somebody help me find a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cou can try this :

```
function manipulate(yourArray) {
  var res = {}
  for (var i=0; i<yourArray.length; i++) {
    if (!res.hasOwnProperty(yourArray[i].type)){
      res[yourArray[i].type] = []
    }
    res[yourArray[i].type].push(yourArray[i])
  }
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should revisit using [groupBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy). I just tried it on your input sample and it produces the exact output you want:

```
_.groupBy(array, 'type');
```